getActiveSpan() for traces in TS wiithout callback
The getActiveSpan() in @opentelemetry/api has a callback implementation where I have to put my code in the callback function like this:
return tracer.startActiveSpan('rollTheDice', (span: Span) => {
    const result: number[] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < rolls; i++) {
      result.push(rollOnce(min, max));
    }

    span.end();
    return result;
  });

The issue is, it leaves a possibility for callback hell if I need multiple child spans and makes the code ugly.
I want to create child spans without using callback function, is there a way to achieve it? I tried promisifying it, but that didn't work.
